# How to implement a session mechanism for an always-open SaaS platform

Tags: mysql, node.js, session, token, saas

The SaaS platform I'm working on should have a rather desktop-app-esque feel to it. Meaning it would be the main management software for my client's businesses and will be always open on their machines.

I'm contemplating on what would be the best way to manage **sessions** for this type of platforms.

The requirements are as follows:

- Sessions should be permanent and never expire (unless explicitly logged out)
- Avoid validating the session against the DB on every request
- Specific sessions should be able to be revoked via the backend
- Stating the obvious - all of the above while not compromising on the security & integrity of the system

It's based on NodeJS/Express, MySQL stack.

Comment: I think you would have better luck over at: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @FrankerZ when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)